# How to secure mysql database credentails for Flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter

I am creating flutter desktop app with local mysql database. How to do secure the db creds so that it is not easily accesible. Is there a secure way to store db credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Prateek's answer is fine for non secret items, but not for credentials. In windows, shared preferences are stored as plain text in your appData folder. With credentials you should look for: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

You will find examples there.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by calling the getInstance() method: SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences. getInstance(); Once you have an instance of SharedPreferences , you can use it to store data using the set method.

Comment: can you please elaborate do not understand

Comment: This is not safe for credentials. SharedPreferences store these things in plain text. Good for the amount of times a user logged in an app, bad for anything security related.